# Test Chatter Rest API endpoint url

Tags: community, rest-api, api, chatter

I have a community user who needs to hit a chatter rest api endpoint. Is there any way to test if the user can hit the api.

It is a community user so i cannot use workbench.

Comment: Why does your community user need to access chatter rest endpoint? He can use chatter ui.

Comment: Actually he needs some user details in his community page. Can we do that by chatter ui? @PranayJaiswal

Comment: Can you provide what details? It can happen we can querry and display it no need to access rest API. Is it lightning community or classic VF+Apex community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need workbench to access any REST API endpoints. What you need is:

- User profile setup appropriately to be able to access APIs ([API enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_userperms.htm&type=5))
- [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_overview.htm&type=5) for [OAuth 2.0 authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_defining_remote_access_applications.htm)
- Any tool viz., [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to be able to call REST API

As long as you have the pre-requisite, any User set in Salesforce will be able to access REST API endpoints.

Comment: I have another added question. I was trying to access the following endpoint /chatter/users/batch/0051I000000cKfWQAU   Here 0051I000000cKfWQAU is a user Id. What is happening is that the address fields are coming up as null. However, if I use /services/data/v41.0/connect/communities/0DB290000004CaOGAU/user-profiles/00529000001vEWK, adress fields are coming up properly. Is there any particular reason this is happening? The end points are being hit by a community user @JayantDas

Comment: Because the original question and the one in your comment are totally different, I would recommend to post this as a separate question with more details so that it can be looked upon.

Comment: can i modify this question? Do you know the answer? I am allowed to post only once every 40 minutes @JayantDas

Comment: Considering your limitation, you may like to edit your original post and put numbers to your questions. As for your other question, are you sure you are using the same user id in both the endpoints, at least the ones you have provided here don't seem to have the same ids, and that may be the reason.

Comment: I tried with the same Ids. Ok let me try this. Can it be a permission issue of the user field had both the urls not worked? @JayantDas. I apologize for the messy question, but I a very new to integration

Comment: I cannot be sure until I really try the endpoints. However I would recommend as long as you are getting the desired results with one of the endpoints, continue using that instead. Anything beyond that will need some research to be able to see what is the issue. As long as you are using the same user to access the endpoint, same id in the request, ideally you should receive the same response if the endpoints are designed to behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are attempting to test the connection to the Chatter API REST Endpoint. You could use the following tools to verify your connection and get a sense of the expected request and the JSON response returned.

- REST Explorer provided by [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php?startUrl=%2FrestExplorer.php)
- [Google Chrome Extension for PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)
- curl (A command line utility to perform calls to service endpoints)